# Need to know requirements for lcd module connector for raspberry pi 2

Tags: hdmi, screen, pitft, connectors

I need to hook up a high brightness 5 inch LCD module to Raspberry Pi 2, but besides HDMI option I don't know much about RPi interfaces available for screen connection.

Most screens I can find have 40pin output available, some have 45pin.

I found a connection board for 40 pin screen [here](http://www.adafruit.com/product/2218).

But the screen I need (enough brightness) is a [G057VN01 V2](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/AUO-5-7-inch-TFT-LCD-Screen-G057VN01-V2-VGA-640-RGB-480/32215381335.html)

Will I be able to connect the lcd module to RPi and use it? If not, what is the general acceptance criteria when selecting a screen for Pi? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi hardware outputs composite video and HDMI (and can output a low resolution VGA if you are prepared to sacrifice most of the usable GPIOs).

Some LCD screens may be driven from SPI, I2C, or parallel GPIO. They tend to be medium to low resolution.  They use driver chips such as agm1264k, bd663474, hx83xxx, ili93xx,  ili94xx, pcd8544, ra8875, s6dxxxx, ssd1xxx, st7735r, tinylcd, tls8204, uc1701, upd161704, watterott.

Unless your LCD screen accepts composite video, VGA, or HDMI, or uses one of the mentioned driver chips it's probaly best to think again.